# How to group similar or very much similar items in list using regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Want to create a new list from another larger list containing similar items from the larger list..My larger list contains values [Everton, QPR, Arsenal, Eveton, Manchester, Leicester, Leicster  ..etc]

Wanted to find a way to create new lists containing largely similar items from the list above using regex..ie Everton and Eveton should be included in new list as they are largely similar.

Dont have code as I don't know how to do such an operation

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this thread: [`fuzzywuzzy`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383044/fuzzy-string-comparison) - you'll certainly won't succeed with a regex alone solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an ["edit distance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) algorithm.  There are a bunch of them, but a common "textbook" one is [Levenshtein's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

There are some Python libraries of course, and also a relevant question with answers here: [Edit Distance in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460177/edit-distance-in-python)