# How to find a string occurrence in another string

Tags: python

One way to check if string contains text:

```
text = 'somewhere over the rainbow'
keyword = 'Rainbow'

if keyword.lower() in str(text).lower():
    print 'yes, it is'
```

Is there a shorter way?

Comment: You don't need `str(text)`. `text` is already a string.

Comment: Just `if keyword.lower() in text.lower():...` is enough.

Comment: if you want to explore more advance version of string occurrence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383044/fuzzy-string-comparison

Comment: "a more elegant way of doing the same" You don't find `inner.lower() in outer.lower()` elegant? Boy, don't spend too much time in other languages! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [find()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm) method:

```
if text.lower().find(keyword.lower()) != -1:
    print 'yes, it is'
```