# Path column and name column need to be associated how to form such association?

Tags: python, pandas

My issue right now is pretty simple i have the following dataset
[image: Dataset]

And i want the path column to be aligned to it is specific pokemon, so basically if the path ends up in an pikachu image i want the Name row and the path row to also be the pikachu image path.

Here is my code and what i tried so far

```
for i in pok['Paths']:
split_path=i.split('/')
#print(split_path[5]
    if split_path[5] == pok['Name'][0]:
        pok['new_path'] == i
```

Unfurtunately i couldnt even make the first path equal..., that was my desperate attempt.
Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should try to do a [fuzzy string search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383044/fuzzy-string-comparison).

```
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import process
>>>
>>> name = df['Name'].tolist()
>>> paths = df['Paths'].tolist()
>>>
>>> mat=[]
>>> for i in name:
...    mat.append(process.extract(i, paths, limit=2)) #mat1
>>> df['new_path'] = mat #mat1
```

Comment: Yours worked perfectly love u, just a lil typo on mat variable but it is fine thank you for introducing me to that library

Answer (score 1):

The following code will extract image name without extension from `Paths` column and save it in `Name` column.

```
import os


pok['Name'] = pok['Paths'].apply(
    lambda x: os.path.basename(x).split('.')[0]
)
```

`os.path.basename` extracts "venomoth.png" from "../input/images/images/venomoth.png"

`.split('.')[0]` extracts "venomoth" from "venomoth.png"

Comment: Apreciate your answer, but to extract the name from the path itself is not exact wat i want. i just want the path that goes to the the pikachu img to be aligned with the Name row Pikachu